# How do I create a lightbox in AppDrag?

Tags: youtube, content-management-system, bootstrap-lightbox

I would like to have a **Youtube video play** in lightbox format.  Is there a way to achieve that using the AppDrag **CMS editor**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a new page in your project.
Keep the page format as a landing page, removing thus the header/footer.

in the new page, click on the "+" button on the left then click on ELEMENTS > Medias and  Drag a youtube element into the blank section and remove the placeholder text there.

Right click on the section containing the video, click on SECTION > Edit > Position and there check the "full height" checkbox.

Go back to your original page.
Open the button you would like to use to trigger the video, and select the Link tab. 
Scroll to Website Page -> select the page you have created earlier.
Then a bit lower, still in the Link tab, select "Open in -> Modal".